# How to access my application in JBoss?

Tags: jboss, geoserver

I'm learning how to use Jboss AS, so sorry for the stupid question.

I installed JBoss 7.1.1 Final and downloaded the geoserver application in the war format.

I fixed the issues that I found and I got no stacktraces when deploying the app.

```
21:55:07,808 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /geoserver
21:55:08,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 5) JBAS018559: Deployed "geoserver.war"
```

But when I access localhost:8080/geoserver I get a 404. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there is a resource mapped at the root context of your webapp?

Comment: Are you sure there are not some other Exceptions in server log?